# Nested list in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, list, confluence

I am using an embedded draw.io diagram in Confluence, and I can't seem to find a way to create a nested list. In Confluence, you can add markup, which does the trick, but draw.io doesn't seem to support that feature.

How to create a one level nested list inside a diagram of draw.io?

Example (where bullets are represented by stars):

```
* first                           
    a
    b
* second
    c
* third
    d
```

---

<sub>My desperate solution is adding whitespaces after the list item, until the nested list item goes to the next line and the indentation level I want (awful, doesn't scale, breaks easily, inconsistent).</sub>

Comment: To downvoter: Please explain what is wrong with the question. I searched a lot (if not the whole) related Internet results, and I couldn't find a result of "how-to-do" or "not possible". Moreover, I explained my attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From draw.io support in Google groups:

[image]

Note: If  I try to embed that into a colored container, it will push the colored background, in order to embed itself.

PS: I ended up using a pool, instead of a container with a nested list inside, in order to do my work..